# Commentaries for Shiva taking linga form from Shiva Maha Purana

Tags: shiva-purana, shiva-lingam, book-recommendation, interpretation, commentary

Puranas of Sanatha dharma allows different types of interpretations. Some are historical, some are metaphorical, some are symbolical, some are allegorical, some are scientific facts including astronomy etc.,

The actual truth can be obtained from the commentaries of great practitioners of Sanathan Dharma.

There is a [story](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226513.html) in Shiva Purana describing an incident of Lord Shiva taking a linga form and Parvathi taking Yoni form. The story is from Chapter 12 of Koti Rudra Samhitha of the [Shiv Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english).

In short, Lord Shiva performed a Leela and most of the Leelas are generally misunderstood by many people. I think, the same is happening with the Leela of Shiva taking the form of Linga as described in the scripture Shiva Purana.

In this context, is there any commentary by any great practitioners of sanathan dharma for the story cited above?

**Note**: Please read the story from the link I provided. It is long enough and hence I did not paste it here.